# Variants in graphical presentation of real and complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

It's standard nowadays for the real line to be horizontal (negative numbers on the left, positive numbers on the right) and for $i$ to be above (rather than below) 0 in the complex plane. Were these conventions universally adhered to in the past?

For instance, I don't know how Argand and Wessel and Gauss actually drew the complex plane.

For that matter, did Oresme (who used something resembling Cartesian coordinates) always draw time as going from left to right, and time-varying quantities on a vertical axis?

(This question is also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286637/variants-in-graphical-presentation-of-real-and-complex-numbers at MathOverflow. I'm new to HSM, so please feel free to correct my tags if others would be more appropriate.)

Comment: Also related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177212/when-did-coordinate-plane-as-we-know-it-come-into-play

Comment: The following paper gives an account of Argand's 1806 representation of complex numbers in the plane based on proportional means.  Please see page 2-3 of  http://mathforum.org/pcmi/briefs/2011revisions/history_brief.pdf .